# neo4j get nodes in order of connections

Tags: neo4j, cypher

http://console.neo4j.org/r/z1iafh is it possible to return n.name in order so it would be CREATE (node_name); without adding new properties to nodes? I see that there is a sequence in which nodes in this test database are connected to each other, so i am interested is it possible to somehow het this sequence.

[image]

```
START n=node(*) MATCH (n)-[r:CREATE_NODE_COMMAND]->(m) RETURN n
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to declare a `path` identifier, then add depth and lastly  you can order by path length :

```
START n=node(*) MATCH p=(n)-[r:CREATE_NODE_COMMAND*..10]->(m)
ORDER BY length(p)
LIMIT 1
RETURN nodes(p)
```

Comment: Returned paths does have depth but it's only 1 `START n=node(*) MATCH p=(n)-[r:CREATE_NODE_COMMAND]->(m) WITH n,p,m ORDER BY length(p) LIMIT 5 RETURN length(p)`  https://yadi.sk/i/aZadQdqNh7byq

Comment: ok so why in your question : order by relationship depth? all will be 1

Comment: Hm. You are right. I need to order by relationship**s**?) the problem is - i need to get this https://yadi.sk/i/hS-h2aQ9h7cGD in order. But the only order i have - is the order in which relationships following one each other...

Comment: http://console.neo4j.org/r/qgjtp0 is it possible to return n.name in order so it would be  CREATE (node_name); without adding new properties to nodes? I see that there is a sequence in which nodes in this test database are connected to each other, so i am interested is it possible to somehow het this sequence.

Comment: The query in the console you shared is only missing the CREATE right? If you include depth 0, does it help? START n=node(*)
MATCH p=(n)-[r:CREATE_NODE_COMMAND*0]->(m)
WITH n,p,m
ORDER BY length(p)
RETURN n.name

Comment: The problem I see is that you have no way to tell what should be the first node ? or should it be always a node that have a "CREATE" statement ?

Comment: Yes, Christophe, i have no way. And i need to get this query in order. I found a way to get amount of relationships between first and last node `MATCH (n { name: 'Create node' })<-[r*]-(s { name: ';' })
WITH n,s, LENGTH(r) AS depth
RETURN n,s, depth` now i am searching a way to print relationship between them

Comment: Luanne i think it's just a bug with console here is new link http://console.neo4j.org/r/z1iafh

Comment: @PavelVanchugov you can return the relationship by adding in your RETURN statement : RETURN n,r,s

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen yes, got it) `MATCH p=(n { name: 'Create node' })<-[r*]-(s { name: ';' }) 
WITH n,s, LENGTH(r) AS depth, nodes(p) as nodes 
RETURN n,s, depth, nodes[1..length(nodes)-1]`

Comment: but the order is still a question